# Why does django Unittest throw an assertion error when comparing two instances of numpy.float64?

Tags: python, django, pandas, numpy, django-unittest

I'm writing some unit tests, one of which checks that the data provided in a dataframe is of the correct type (float).

When I run the test `assertIsInstance(type(foo), np.float64)` the test fails with the following error message: `AssertionError <class numpy.float64> is not an instance of <class numpy.float64>`

I would have expected this to pass.

test_dataframe_functions.py

```
import numpy as np
from django.test import TestCase
import pandas as pd
from myapp import dataframe_functions

class DataframeFunctionsTest(TestCase):
    dataframe_to_test = dataframe_functions.create_dataframe

    #passes
    def test_dataframe_is_definitely_a_dataframe(self):
        self.assertIsInstance(self.dataframe_to_test, pd.DataFrame)

    #passes
    def test_dataframe_has_the_right_columns(self):
        column_headers = list(self.dataframe_to_test.columns)
        self.assertEquals(column_headers, ['header1', 'header2', 'header3'])

    #fails with AssertionError <class numpy.float64> is not an instance of <class numpy.float64>
    def test_dataframe_header1_is_correct_format(self):
        data_instance = self.dataframe_to_test['header1'].iloc[1]
        self.assertIsInstance(type(data_instance), np.float64)
```

I've checked that `type(data_instance)` does equal "class numpy.float64" with the following line of code:

`print(type(dataframe_to_test['header1'].iloc[1]))`

Comment: Do you notice how you didn't call `type` in the one that worked?

Comment: `IsInstance` should be called with `assertIsInstance(object, type)`, so `assertIsInstance(foo, np.float64)`.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica - I do now!  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because a `type` object is indeed *not* an instance of an `np.float64`. The `assertIsInstance` method should be called with `assertIsInstance(object, type)`, and it thus checks if `object` is an instance of a (subtype of) `type`. A `type` object is not an instance of `np.float64`.

You thus should call this with:

```
assertIsInstance(foo, np.float64)
```

not with:

```
assertIsInstance(type(foo), np.float64)
```